# How to set request headers by Ajax

Tags: ajax, header, request

I trying to set request headers by two ways:
1:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "https://d.la1-c1-lon.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/System/SessionId",
headers: {
    "X-LIVEAGENT-API-VERSION" : 34,
    "X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY" : null
},
response:'json'
});
```

2:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-LIVEAGENT-API-VERSION', 34);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY', null);
    },
url: "https://d.la1-c1-lon.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/System/SessionId",   
response:'json'
});
```

In browser console I waiting for "X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY:null" and "X-LIVEAGENT-API-VERSION:34".
But really I see "Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, x-liveagent-affinity, x-liveagent-api-version"